# como mostrar .gif en QLabel Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Buenos dias quisiera saber si hay alguna manera en la que pueda mostrar un archivo.gif en una qlabel.

Actualmente solo he intentado esto:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel



class Nueva(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.l = QLabel(self)
        self.l.resize(150,150)
        self.l.setStyleSheet('Background-image:{};'.format('anima.gif'))






app = QApplication([])
n = Nueva()
n.resize(900,600)
n.show()
app.exec_()
```

pero no funciono agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es implementar un `QMovie` dentro de una `QLabel`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel
from PyQt5.Qt import QMovie



class Nueva(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.l = QLabel(self)
        self.l.resize(150,150)
        self.movi = QMovie("anima.gif")
        self.l.setMovie(self.movi)
        self.movi.start()





app = QApplication([])
n = Nueva()
n.resize(900,600)
n.show()
app.exec_()
```